# Prove that for any injective $f: A \to B$ and bijective $g: B \to C$ a function $h$ can be defined so that $h(g(f(x))) = x$ for all $x \in A$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, inverse

I've struggled for a few hours with a convincing enough proof of the following.

Let

$A = \{\textrm{red}, \textrm{green}, \textrm{blue}\}$

$B = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$

$C = \{\textrm{cat}, \textrm{dog}, \textrm{rabbit}, \textrm{turtle}\}$

$f: A \to B$ an injective function and $g: B \to C$ a bijective function.

Prove that for any choices of $f$ and $g$ a function $h: C \to A$ can be defined so that $h(g(f(x))) = x$ for all $x \in A$.

I initially went down some paths involving showing that various compositions of $f$, $g$, and $h$ are injective or surjective and as such can serve as inverses etc. But then I realised that $h$ can never be bijective since $A$ and $C$ have a different number of elements and I went back to square one.

This is my current proof:

> Since $f$ is injective and $D_f = A$ then $V_f$ will always consist of three distinct elements in $B$ regardless of how $f$ is defined. Since also $g$ is injective, $V_g$ will always consist of three distinct elements in $C$ regardless of how $g$ is defined. (We're really saying that $g \circ f$ is injective since by definition $g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) \implies f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$.) Since $D_h$ is larger than $A$ we can always define $h$ so that $V_h = A$, in other words that it is surjective, and so that each $y \in C$ is the image of the respective $x \in A$. We then have a function $h: C \in A$ that satisfies that $h(g(f(x))) = x$ for all $x \in A$. Note that it's not required for $g$ to be surjective or $h$ to be injective to always be able to define $h$ accordingly. In fact, $h$ can never be injective since $A$ and $C$ have a different number of elements.

What do you think? Am I completely off the track here? Although this is maybe the least stringent proof I have produced so far, it is to myself the most convincing one, unless I've missed some fatal flaw in the logic.

Any suggestions or comments are much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: any injective function with nonempty domain is a split monomorphism in the category of sets (i.e. has a left inverse called a retraction).

Comment: Although your comment is intriguing, I should mention this is an assignment in a first-year level undergrad course on real analysis – and in an engineering programme. Abstract concepts such as monomorphism and categories are probably too far into pure math to be applicable in this assignment. But I really appreciate learning some new words to read up on.

Answer (score 1):

Since, as you say, $g \circ f$ is injective, we can set
$$
h(x) =
\begin{cases}
(g \circ f)^{-1}(x) & (g\circ f)^{-1}(\{x\}) \neq \emptyset \\
a & (g\circ f)^{-1}(\{x\}) = \emptyset
\end{cases}
$$
where $(g\circ f)^{-1}(x)$ is the unique element in $(g\circ f)^{-1}(\{x\})$, and $a$ is some fixed element of $A$.

Take $x \in A$, and set $y = (g \circ f)(x)$. Then $(g \circ f)^{-1}(y)  = x$. Hence $$h(g(f(x))) = h((g\circ f) (x)) = h(y) = (g \circ f)^{-1}(y) = x$$

Because of how I defined $h$, we should probably consider the case where $A = \emptyset$. In this case, the only function $h : C \to A$ is the empty function, and $h(g(f(x))) = x$ is trivially true for all $x \in A$ (since there are no $x \in A$!).

Comment: This is a very nice proof. It looks like a much more stringent version of something I dabbled with yesterday where I identified that $(g \circ f)^{-1}$ would satisfy the conditions for $h$ but I couldn't express it in any good way. Thanks!

Comment: Note that I'm careful to not assume that $(g \circ f)^{-1}$ exists as a function. Rather, $(g \circ f)^{-1}(\{x\}) = \{y \in A : (g \circ f)(y) = x\}$, and, per my notation, $(g \circ f)^{-1}(x)$ is just the unique element in that set. The function $(g \circ f)^{-1}$ does not exist unless $g \circ f$ is a bijection.

Comment: Is the distinction clear, and is it clear why the distinction must be made?

Comment: As I understand it, if we would assume $(g \circ f)^{-1}$ always exists we will suddenly also have said $g \circ f$ is always a bijection, since that is a prerequisite, and nothing in the problem statement tells us we can make any such assumption.

Comment: Yeah. To see what's going on for yourself, write down a specific $f$ which is injective but not surjective and a specific bijection $g$. Check that $(g \circ f)^{-1}(\{x\})$ as I have defined it above is the empty set for at least one $x \in C$. Thus, there are elements of $C$ where $(g \circ f)^{-1}(x)$ isn't even defined. That's why I have to break my definition of $h$ into cases.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The essence of your argument is sound, good job!

Of course, giving a single example or even privileging a single example in a proof is not a good form, so your proof shouldn't be stating that $A$ has three members in it.  The proof works perfectly well even if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are infinite sets.  You also don't want to refer to the fact that $A$ and $C$ don't have the same number of elements, because there's nothing in the statement of the proof to suggest that $f$ can't be surjective.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm happy to hear I'm not lost. I should add that this is just a piece of homework for my single variable calculus class so generalising it to e.g. infinite sets is probably outside the scope of the exercise. I've omitted here that this is actually the fourth part of an exercise where parts 1-3 was to explicitly define some $f$, $g$ and $h$ to have these properties and that the sets are given in the exercise. I consider it implied that $f$ should be injective and not surjective. In any case, your input is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should allow for the possibility that $f$ is also surjective. In math, it is very rare that if something is only said to have a more general property that it is assumed not to have the more specific property. In fact, it is so rare that I can't think of an example. To be concrete, if someone says $f$ is injective, that should not be taken to mean "$f$ is injective and not surjective." Instead, you should read that as "$f$ is at least surjective."

Comment: That's good advice. I will probably work on this some more before I hand it in, there is no reason to make it just good enough.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo at the most crucial moment. The last part of that last sentence should read "$f$ is at least injective."

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to require that $A \neq \emptyset$ and both $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$ are injective, with neither one required to be bijective.

Since $f$ and $g$ are injective, so is their composition $g \circ f:A \to C$. Also, any injection with nonempty domain has a left inverse (send elements of the image to their unique preimages and other elements of the codomain to some random element of the domain, which exists since the domain is assumed to be nonempty). In particular, $g \circ f$ has a left inverse $h:C \to A$ for which $\forall a \in A \ h(g(f(a)))=a$ (since $A$ is nonempty).

Similarly, if $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$ are surjective functions, then the composition $g \circ f:A \to C$ is also surjective, and has a right inverse $h:C \to A$ for which $\forall c \in C \ g(f(h(c)))=c$ (assuming the axiom of choice).

Comment: It is very useful knowledge that any injection with a non-empty domain has a left inverse. I haven't delved into left vs. right vs. inverse yet but I think I might soon.